# Question on Proposition 10.3 Neukirch - Splitting of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

in the law of decomposition of prime numbers p into prime ideals of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ (Proposition 10.3 Neukirch ANT) with $\zeta$ the n-th root of unity, he tries to proof the congruence $\Phi_n(X) = \Phi_m(X)^{\varphi(p^{\nu_p})}$ mod $p$ where $n = p^{n_p}m$.

Whilst I get that $X^{\nu_p}-1 = (X-1)^{p^{\nu_p}}$ mod $p$ by Frobenius, I don't understand why that implies that the corresponding $p^{\nu_p}$-th roots of unity ($\eta_j$) are $\eta_j = 1$ mod $\mathfrak{p}$ for primes $\mathfrak{p}|p$.

P.S: I've tried to calculate it explicitly for $2^2 =4$. There we have the primitive roots of unity $\pm i$, and one of the prime ideals should be $\mathfrak{p} = 2\mathbb{Z}[i]$. However, $i \neq 1$ mod $\mathfrak{p}$. Is there something wrong with this calculation?

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}[i]$ isn’t prime, though.

Comment: @Aphelli i just realized that obviously, 2Z[i] decomposes as (i+1)^2 in Z[i]. However, my question now is how do we get from the Frobenius which is mod p (i.e. in my explicit example mod 2) to mod $\mathfrak{p}$ in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Plug $\eta_j$ into $X^{\nu_p} -1 \equiv (X - 1)^{p^{\nu_p}} \bmod p$.  Since $\eta_j^{p^{\nu_p}} = 1$ that means $(\eta_j - 1)^{p^{\nu_p}} \equiv 0 \bmod p$ and so $(\eta_j - 1)^{p^\nu_p} \in p\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$.  Since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, $(\eta_j - 1) \in \mathfrak{p}$, that is, $\eta_j \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak{p}$.